# How to stop infinite while loop

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

When the code below is true, meaning that when the first and last characters match it loops forever till I exit out the code, how do I fix it?

```
while (true) {
    // Ignores case and checks if the firstLetters and lastLetters are the same
    if (firstLetters.equalsIgnoreCase(lastLetters)) 
    {
        // if they are then print out this
        System.out.println("The first two letters and the last two are the same!");
    }
    else
    {   
        System.out.println("Different :("); // If they are different print out this
        System.out.println("Continue? [Y/N]");
        String ans = in.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Please enter a string longer than 4 letters");
        word=in.nextLine();
        // Ignores case and checks if the firstLetters and lastLetters are the same
        if (firstLetters.equalsIgnoreCase(lastLetters)) 
        {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You never update `firstLetters` and `lastLetters`.

Comment: sorry, what do you mean? Im new to this

Comment: He means they're never changed.

Comment: what do you want to do, could you explain in more details?

Answer (score 0):

Nowhere in your code do you have updates to the `firstLetters` and `lastLetters` variables, so the same checks are executed repeatedly.

If you want to avoid the while(true) and break needs, you could specify your break criteria in the while loop definition itself... just a thought.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add some more code:-

```
word=in.nextLine();
// New code
firstLetters = word.substring(0, 1);
lastLetters = word.substring(word.length()-1, 1);

// As you were...
if (firstLetters.equalsIgnoreCase(lastLetters))
```

You also need to finished the `} else` after `System.out.println("Different :(");`, so the user is always asked if they want to enter another word.  As it is, you only ask them if the words are different.

Answer (score 0):

just put a break statement in the first if after printing the message

```
if (firstLetters.equalsIgnoreCase(lastLetters)) //Ignores case and checks if the firstLetters and lastLetters are the same
{
    System.out.println("The fist two letters and the last two are the same!");//if they are than print out this
    break;
}
```

Comment: But if i do that then it went ask the user again if they want to continue using the program

Comment: put the asking out of the if else. mean ask the user regardless of the his result

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to understand what you want to do here. I suppose you want to keep asking for the user to input words to be checked until he wants to quit. If that is the case, then you should place the question outside the if-else statement, the logic should go something like this:

```
while (true) {
    // Get the word
    System.out.println("Please enter a string longer than 4 letters");
    word=in.nextLine();

    // Get the letters
    firstLetters = word.substring(0, 1);
    lastLetters = word.substring(word.length()-1, 1);

    // Ignores case and checks if the firstLetters and lastLetters are the same
    if (firstLetters.equalsIgnoreCase(lastLetters)) 
    {
        // if they are then print out this
        System.out.println("The first two letters and the last two are the same!");
    }
    else
    {   
        System.out.println("Different"); // If they are different print out this
    }

    // Asks  the user if he wnats to keep inputing words
    System.out.println("Continue? [Y/N]");
    String ans = in.nextLine();

    // The user wants to quit, breaks from the loop
    if(ans.equals("N")){
         break;
    }


}
```